# Create/Change Custom Table Dynamically

Tags: magento-1.9, module, database

I'm wondering if there is any possibility of creating Custom Table outside install or update script, and without using the query("CREATE TABLE statement"), in Magento 1.9+

Answer (score 2):

The Magento way of creating tables **in install scripts** is not using raw SQL but the Zend API:

```
$table = $installer->getConnection()
    ->newTable($installer->getTable('my/custom_table'))
    ->addColumn('id', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_INTEGER, null, array(
        'identity'  => true,
        'unsigned'  => true,
        'nullable'  => false,
        'primary'   => true,
        ), 'ID')
    ->addColumn(...);
$installer->getConnection()->createTable($table);
```

More on the topic: http://inchoo.net/magento/magento-install-install-upgrade-data-and-data-upgrade-scripts/

---

You can do the same **anywhere else** if you replace `$installer->getConnection()` with `Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_write');`.

Comment: Many Thanks @fschmengler , I'm going to try creating a table using Controller's Action (at the BackEnd).